# Is there any similar techniques/services like console app in .net technology for MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, mean-stack

We have a web & console application in .net technology. The console app will be run through the web application by passing required params for analysis and report purpose.. The console tool will executed by pragmatically and then tool will run independently to generate the data for analysis and reports.

Now we are trying to change the technology from .NET to MEAN stack. We have already developed the web application. Is there any techniques/services in MEAN stack like console app ? So that i can execute the tool/service separately to generate the data for reports like .NET.

If no techniques, please suggest me How to achieve this in MEAN stack ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I wouldn't think it was possible in the .NET world either. May I ask *how* you are getting a Web application to run a console app? I didn't think that was possible. If we better understood how you are getting it to work in the .NET world, we may be able to make some suggestions.

Comment: @ DeborahK We have one Windows service, it will make a console tool to run. The web application is used to select and submit (insert) the params into a "Jobs" table with "QUEUED" status. 
The windows service keeps on check the Jobs table periodically to fetch the "QUEUED" status jobs and start the console tool with job params (using Process class in c#).
Once the tool was started successfully then that job status will be changed from QUEUED to RUNNING in jobs table.

Answer (score 1):

The MEAN stack includes Node.js, which can be used to create a command line application.

You can get command line arguments inside a Node.js JavaScript file using `process.argv`:

> process.argv is an array containing the command line arguments. The
>   first element will be 'node', the second element will be the name of
>   the JavaScript file. The next elements will be any additional command
>   line arguments.

You can then execute the file by running `node file.js argument1 argument2`.